# Are these correct and which one is used the most?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

My salary was reduced by 20%. 
My salary was cut 20%. 
My pay was reduced by 20%.
My pay was cut 20%.

Can you also say: 
My salary was reduced quite a lot. 
My pay was cut quite a lot.

I am curious, which one is used the most.
If the sentences above are grammatically wrong, sound unnatural or there is a better way to say them, please let me know.

Comment: All of these sentences sound fine to me. They are different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: Both sentences are grammatically correct, but not *quite* saying the same thing - one is more specific than the other. 
In English, "salary" refers to jobs that are paid at an annual rate, as opposed to "wages" which refer to jobs that are paid by the hour - for example: fast food workers, retail workers etc. 
"Pay" is a more general term whose meaning encompasses "salary", "wages" and other methods of earning money.

Answer (score 1):

All of your sentences are grammatically correct, make perfect sense, and all would be considered "normal" by a fluent English speaker.